# How to set the format of a cell defined by other cells in Google Sheets from a custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Been trying to sort this out for a bit.

I have a sheet that takes inputs in the form of two values and a color.

I want to take these values and assign the color to a cell in another tab/sheet whose address matches the numbers (so getting 3,2,red would make cell C2 red).

I think I'm close, but I run into a few things with this:

```
function CopyF(target,color){
  var color;
  var target;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
  var tgt = sht2.getRange(target);
  var range = sheet.getRange(color);
  var bg = range.getBackground();
  tgt.setBackground(bg);
}
```

First, if I leave "target" in line 8, I get "Range not found".  But I can put a defined value ("B2" for example) and it'll accept that. The same thing sometimes happens on line 9.

Second, if I leave it as is (allowing it to be called as a function on the sheet with inputs...I think) it won't complete a test run and leaves me with a "You don't have permission for setBackground().  If I force a specific set of cells it will run but is rendered useless for what I want to complete.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: Don't you have to input as parameters a `targetColumn` and a `targetRow` in addition to the `color`?  I would think the `target` parameter does not fully specify a range (row, column).

Comment: I found an alternative.  I was able to send the values of the sheet where colors are input from the form by text to the second sheet and used conditional formatting to color the cells of the second sheet according to the text value.